# Docker container giving 503 error while running php application

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, http-status-code-503

I have a dockerfile to build an image having php installed

```
FROM centos:latest
RUN yum install  net-tools -y
RUN yum install  httpd -y
RUN yum install php -y
ENV REFRESHED AT "04-06-2016"
ADD index.php /var/www/html/
```

the index.php file is looking like this

```
<?php
print("welcome to php");
print("\n\n");
print `ifconfig`;
?>
```

I am building the image from command

```
docker build -t myimage .
```

then i am running a container from command

```
docker container run -it --name os1 myimage
```

then from the container , I am starting the service from command

```
usr/sbin/httpd
```

it is giving me the this warning

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

But if i run command `curl 172.17.0.2` from my host, it is giving me this output

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>503 Service Unavailable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Service Unavailable</h1>
<p>The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.</p>
</body></html>
```

I didn`t get why i am getting this error .
I tried running each command from dockerfile in container , then it is working fine , but building the image from dockerfile is giving me this error.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a directory that allows php sockets to be created (IDK why its missing)

You just have to create that directory while creating the Docker Image:

```
FROM centos:latest
RUN yum install  net-tools -y
RUN yum install  httpd -y
RUN mkdir /run/php-fpm
RUN yum install php -y
ENV REFRESHED AT "04-06-2016"
ADD index.php /var/www/html/
```

Also once inside the container run `/usr/sbin/php-fpm` after `/usr/sbin/httpd` to start php-fpm and it works...
[Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05wrG.png)

Comment: Yes , Now it is working . can you tell me how did you figured out this solution . how did you debug this?